How to manually close ssh ports / port bindings?
I work on a mac 15.1 system and open a connection to a jumpserver for having the option to connect to several other servers.
Usually the script works like a charm, but sometimes it gets stuck and nothing beside a complete reboot of my Mac works to get the bound ports to open again.
I am using iTerm2 as terminal on a Mac OS 15.1.
Here is the script:
#!/bin/sh

username="myusername"
jumpServer="vl-com-jfd-p01.example.com"
# shellcheck disable=SC2039
hosts=("gl-d-foo.d.gcp.example.com" "192.168.0.234" "vl-web-int-d02" "10.40.13.44" "172.16.20.88" "10.245.131.226" "gl-p-foo.p.gcp.example.com" )

destSshPort=22
destMysqlPort=3306

x=10021
y=10022


for i in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  :
  server=$i
  sshTunnel="$sshTunnel -L $x:$server:$destMysqlPort -L $y:$server:$destSshPort"
  echo "Server: $server -- MYSQL: $x -- SSH: $y"
  x=$((x + 2))
  y=$((y + 2))
done


if [ -z "$sshTunnel" ]
then
  echo "ssh tunnels are empty"
else
  ssh $sshTunnel $username@$jumpServer
fi

After calling this script and a successfull connection to the jumpserver I open a second shell and connect to one of the server by typing something like this:
ssh -p10022 -L 9994:10.239.244.31:3306 myusername@localhost

This all works fine so there is nothing wrong with the script per se.
But sometimes I loose the connection to the jumpserver and after starting the process again I get the messages like:
bind [127.0.0.1]:10021: Address already in use channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 10021
Even after closing iTerm2 and starting it again.
So here is my question:
how can I free the ports without having to reboot the mac or waiting until they close on their own?
Is there any command with which I can close the ports manually?

Side note: the site is not just for helping you right now. It's also for helping other users with similar problems in the future. In this context "a current " is not as meaningful as it should be.

I already mentioned OS 15.1 on top of the post, but I can remove the other.

Is the old ssh process actually exiting? Run ps, and look for a ssh -L 10021:gl-d-foo.d.gcp.example.com: 3306 ... process. Also, run netstat -an -f inet | grep 10021 and see if it shows the port in "TIME_WAIT" state (see "Why does it take up to several minutes to clean a listening TCP port after a program dies?"), in which case you basically need to wait a couple of minutes (or rewrite the script to detect this and use higher port numbers if necessary).

I will do that the next time it occurs. I just want to mention, that I would not care if we talk about 2 or 4 minutes. Last time the ports still were not available after 2 hours!

Thanks to the comment from @Gordon Davisson I could solve my problem. It had just occurred again after a crash of iTerm2 after an upgrade.
$ netstat -an -f inet | grep 10021
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.10021        *.*                    LISTEN


So I had a look at the results of ps:
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1747 ttys004    0:00.03 -bash
 1807 ttys005    0:00.03 -bash
 2030 ttys006    0:00.03 -bash
 2096 ttys007    0:00.06 -bash
78235 ttys007    1:59.37 ssh -p10022 -L 9994:10.239.244.31:3306 p325111@localhost
 2162 ttys008    0:00.05 -bash
68850 ttys008    0:01.69 ssh -p10022 -R 9003:127.0.0.1:9003 p325111@localhost
 2231 ttys009    0:00.07 -bash
68834 ttys009    0:00.01 /bin/sh ./tunnel.sh
68835 ttys009    4:35.26 ssh -L 10021:foo.d.example.com:3306 -L 10022:foo.d.gcp.puc-mobile.de:22 -L 10023:192.168.0.234
77772 ttys010    0:00.13 -bash
82148 ttys011    0:00.02 -bash
82314 ttys014    0:00.02 -bash
82386 ttys015    0:00.02 -bash
82446 ttys016    0:00.03 -bash
82515 ttys017    0:00.03 -bash
82653 ttys017    0:00.01 /bin/sh ./tunnel.sh
82654 ttys017    0:00.08 ssh -L 10021:foo.d.gcp.puc-mobile.de:3306 -L 10022:foo.d.gcp.puc-mobile.de:22 -L 10023:192.168.0.234

After killing both processes which contained 10021 in my case 68835 and 82654 I could start my connection again and all ports were available. So simple!
